# Script to copy text object and increment value in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, copy-and-paste

I would like to have a hotkey in Adobe Illustrator that copy, paste text object and increment number value inside that object.
For example I select text object with value "1", press hotkey and it creates new text object with value "2" next to previous object. Is it posible?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes ot would be possible. Sounds inoptimal as a workflow though.

Comment: So what is better option?